# How to make a white background effect for video recording?

Tags: video, editing, youtube

I have seen this video on YouTube which has a white background effect with proper video quality.

[image: Video]

How could I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You need a white backdrop with the appropriate backdrop stands!  For the backdrop, you have two choices:

- Muslin fabric.  Easily transported since you can fold it up and bring it wherever you need. But, it does have to be ironed/steamed until it's completely wrinkle-free.

**OR:**

- Paper backdrop.  You don't have to iron/steam wrinkles out of this.  But it's a pain to transport it since it's a super-long roll of thick paper.

To light this scene, you'll need three lights: key light + fill light to light your actor, and third a Fiilex light, [like this one](https://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/1021433-REG/fiilex_flxp360_p360_90w_led_light.html), to place on the ground behind your sitting talent, and pointing upward towards the backdrop.

It's best to turn off all interior lights and block out the windows and only light the scene using these three lights.